# Displaying the top 10 player names and their coins

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was assigned a task to make a leader board

I was making it and i got stuck at making it display more then one person.

```
$SQL = $odb -> query("SELECT username,SUM(kills) AS `kills`
                      FROM `players`
                      GROUP BY username
                      ORDER BY `kills` DESC
                      LIMIT 10");
                  $SQL -> execute();
                  echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
                  echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                  echo $SQL -> fetchColumn(1);
```

and that just make's it display 1 players name then their coins. I need it to display 10 in order from greatest coins to least.

Comment: Well you will need to use some kind of loop for this.

Comment: @Cyclone Now how would i do that :P

Comment: Do you **know** what a loop is? You can always try searching for `loop php` to get an example

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) you can do the following if you use PDO :

```
$sql = "SELECT username,SUM(kills) ASkills
                      FROMplayers
                      GROUP BY username
                      ORDER BYkillsDESC
                      LIMIT 10"
foreach ($odb->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo $row['username'].$row['kills'];
    }
```

You were just missing a loop there.